# confidence intervals compared with standard deviation in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, seaborn

when I use seaborn's confidence intervals in `pointplot` I get deceptively small values, compared with standard error. Example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import pandas
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)
df = pandas.DataFrame({"x": x,
                       "y": y})
data = pandas.melt(df)
print "data: ", data
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
sns.pointplot(x="variable", y="value", data=data)
plt.ylim([0, 0.9])
ax = plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
m = [df["x"].mean(), df["y"].mean()]
e = [df["x"].std(), df["y"].std()]
plt.errorbar(range(1,3), m, yerr=e)
plt.ylim([0, 0.9])
plt.xlim([0, 4])
plt.xticks([1, 2])
ax.set_xticklabels(["x", "y"])
```

the standard deviations are significantly larger. what is the explanation for this? can seaborn plot error bars that are closer to simple metric like standard deviation?

[image]

in the bottom plot, the standard errors for x and y are shown and they are much bigger than seaborn's confidence intervals for x and y (in top plot).

Comment: The `.std()` method computes standard deviation, which is not the same thing as standard error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Making my previous answer below more precise,** since the standard deviation of a uniform random variable is 1/sqrt(12)~=0.2887 the bars in your second plot cover an interval of size roughly [0.5-0.2887,0.5+0.2887]=[0.2113,0.7887].

On the other hand, by the central limit theorem, the 95%-confidence interval of the empirical mean of 100 uniform random variables will be roughly [0.5-1.96*0.2887/sqrt(100),0.5+1.96*0.2887/sqrt(100)]~=[0.443,0.557]. This corresponds to the confidence interval drawn by seaborn in your first plot.

To summarize, for computations of statistical confidence intervals, the sample size plays a critical role and cannot be neglected!

**Previous shorter answer**
Seaplot's confidence-intervals take into account the number of samples that are used to estimate the mean. Given that you handed seaplot a decent number of 100 sample points the 95%-confidence interval for the empirical mean of the 100 sample points will indeed be pretty small.

In order to achieve a fair comparison, you should scale your standard errors by 1/sqrt(100) and then compare the plots.